How to remove user in UI before updating the database?
How can I remove the participant in the client before updating the actual state when submit button is click?
I'm currently using react-hook-form and TanstackQuery. Basically I fetch the data using tanstack query and then on my formfield, I use defaultValues to show the data first, but the problem I'm encountering is, since I have a list of users, I want to delete it on client first
edit/[id]/page/tsx.
const EditAppointment =({params}) => {

  const appoinment = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['appointment', 'data', 'history', id],
    queryFn: () => fetch(`/api/single-sched/${id}`).then((res) => res.json())
  })


  const { data } = appoinment

  const form = useForm<CreateAppointmentSchemaType>({
    resolver: zodResolver(CreateAppointmentSchema),
  });

  const removeAssistant = (name: string) => (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(`Removing assistant: ${name}`);
  }

return (
   <Form {...form}>
     <form>
       <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="title"
            defaultValue={data?.title}
            render={({ field }) => (
                <FormItem>
                  <FormLabel>Title</FormLabel>
                      <FormControl>
                        <Input {...field} />
                      </FormControl>
                    </FormItem>
                  )}
           />


<Table className='max-w-[400px]'>
      <TableHeader>
           <TableRow>
              <TableHead>Name</TableHead>
               <TableHead>Email</TableHead>
               <TableHead></TableHead>
           </TableRow>
              </TableHeader>
                 <TableBody>
                   {data?.name_of_assistance.map((item:{name: string, email: string}) => {
                          return (
                            <TableRow>
                          <TableCell>{item.name}</TableCell>
                          <TableCell>{item.email}</TableCell>
                          <TableCell> 
                            <Button onClick={() => removeAssistant(item.name)}  
           variant="destructive" size="icon">
                              <Trash2 /> 
                            </Button>
                             </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                          )
                        })} 
                      </TableBody>
                    </Table>

     </form>
   <Form />
)
}




Why don't you remove it from database first and make sure it was removed without errors ?

You can maintain a local state using useState hook to manage the local state for the list of participants and update the form when the remove button is clicked, then send the actual update to the backend when the form is submitted.
I have updated your code to add the local state part:
const EditAppointment = ({ params }) => {
  const { id } = params;
  
  const appointment = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['appointment', 'data', 'history', id],
    queryFn: () => fetch(`/api/single-sched/${id}`).then((res) => res.json()),
  });

  const { data } = appointment;

  const [assistants, setAssistants] = useState([]);
 const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data?.name_of_assistance) {
      setAssistants(data.name_of_assistance);
    }
  }, [data]);

  const form = useForm<CreateAppointmentSchemaType>({
    resolver: zodResolver(CreateAppointmentSchema),
    defaultValues: data,
  });

  const removeAssistant = (name: string) => {
    setAssistants((prev) => prev.filter((assistant) => assistant.name !== name));
  };

 const onSubmit = async (formData) => {
    setIsSubmitting(true);
    setError(null);

    try {
      // Add to formData
      formData.name_of_assistance = assistants;

      // Submit  to backend
      const response = await fetch(`/api/update-sched/${id}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed --');
      }

      // happy flow
      console.log('updated successfully');
    } catch (error) {
      // error handling
      console.error(error);
      setError('An error occurred. Please try again.');
    } finally {
      setIsSubmitting(false);
    }
  };


  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="title"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>Title</FormLabel>
              <FormControl>
                <Input {...field} />
              </FormControl>
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />

        <Table className='max-w-[400px]'>
          <TableHeader>
            <TableRow>
              <TableHead>Name</TableHead>
              <TableHead>Email</TableHead>
              <TableHead></TableHead>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHeader>
          <TableBody>
            {assistants.map((item) => (
              <TableRow key={item.name}>
                <TableCell>{item.name}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{item.email}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  <Button
                    onClick={(e) => {
                      e.preventDefault();
                      removeAssistant(item.name);
                    }}
                    variant="destructive"
                    size="icon"
                  >
                    <Trash2 />
                  </Button>
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>

        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
      </form>
    </Form>
  );
};

I have added an onSubmit method which updates the backend when submit is clicked, if however the call fails there is error handling with a try catch block.
Hope this helps!
